# Why is this an error when rendering a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm trying to render a state via props to a nested component. This is what I have in my `App.js`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchResults: [
        {name: 'Money Trees',
        artist: 'Kendrick Lamar',
        album: 'Album Title',
        id: '1234'},

        {name: 'Reptilia',
        artist: 'The Stroks',
        album: 'Is This It',
        id: '234'}
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing
        </h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
            <Playlist />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Inside `Playlist.js` I have this:

```
class Playlist extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Playlist">
        <input defaultValue={'New Playlist'} />
        <Tracklist />
        <a className="Playlist-save"></a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Playlist;
```

Now, I'm able to pass in the tracks props through a `SearchResults` component and into a `Tracklist` component. However, I'm getting an error when trying to map the tracks prop:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

When I remove the Playlist component from the App file, the error fixes itself. I'm not sure why I get the error when I toss in `<Playlist />` inside the main `App.js` file. Can someone help me understand that?

This is what `Tracklist.js` looks like:

```
class Tracklist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.props.tracks.map(track => <Track track={track} key={track.id} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tracklist;
```

Comment: From what I see, you are not passing any data to your `Tracklist` compoment. How does it look like BTW?

Comment: That's exactly it. My friend told me that's the issue. I'm just confused here, I can't render a component without any data?

Comment: Well you can render it, but if you don't pass data it might have not much to show or throw errors like the one you have. In your case I assume `TrackList` component renders tracks and somehow you need to pass the tracks to render as props; if you don't do it, the component has no tracks to render.

Comment: Hmm, Ok I think I understand. I tried passing in `this.state.searchResults` as a random attribute to the Playlist componenet and rendering it with props there but got the same issue. Not sure what gives. But anyway, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

`Playlist` renders `Tracklist` and it expects `tracks` props.

Try:

```
class Playlist extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Playlist">
        <input defaultValue={'New Playlist'} />
        <Tracklist tracks={[]} />
        <a className="Playlist-save"></a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

To see if the error disappears.